# CASE WHEN on WHERE CLAUSE?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an interesting problem. I will write a scalar-valued function. One of the parameters isn't in table columns. I have to use this parameter (@ImpUrgPri) in where clause. As for that parameter, there will be a condition with a column existing in table. Can you help me about that?

```
DECLARE @ImpUrgPri NVARCHAR(3)
SET @ImpUrgPri = 'URG'
DECLARE @Enum INT
SET @Enum = 0

select COUNT(*) 
from zODYA_vwCallReq_AllData 
where ActiveFlag = 1
AND 
(CASE WHEN (@ImpUrgPri = 'PRI') THEN Priority_Enum == @Enum
        WHEN (@ImpUrgPri = 'URG') THEN Urgency_Enum == @Enum 
        WHEN (@ImpUrgPri = 'IMP') THEN Impact_Enum == @Enum END)

group by 
(CASE WHEN (@ImpUrgPri = 'PRI') THEN Priority_Enum 
        WHEN (@ImpUrgPri = 'URG') THEN Urgency_Enum 
        WHEN (@ImpUrgPri = 'IMP') THEN Impact_Enum END)
```

Comment: You already have the code, what's your question?

Comment: That code returns "Incorrect syntax near" error on case when block at where clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your select could be as:

```
select COUNT(*) 
from zODYA_vwCallReq_AllData 
where ActiveFlag = 1
AND @Enum =  (CASE WHEN (@ImpUrgPri = 'PRI') THEN Priority_Enum
             WHEN (@ImpUrgPri = 'URG') THEN Urgency_Enum
             WHEN (@ImpUrgPri = 'IMP') THEN Impact_Enum END)

group by 
(CASE WHEN (@ImpUrgPri = 'PRI') THEN Priority_Enum 
        WHEN (@ImpUrgPri = 'URG') THEN Urgency_Enum 
        WHEN (@ImpUrgPri = 'IMP') THEN Impact_Enum END)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be best to use `IF` and have three different `SELECT`s, one for each "when" case.

You could also create the SQL dynamically (inside the stored procedure), that would make a slightly shorter stored procedure. With just the three options here, I would stick with 3 SELECTs.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @ImpUrgPri NVARCHAR(3)
SET @ImpUrgPri = 'URG'
DECLARE @Enum INT
SET @Enum = 0

select COUNT(*) 
from zODYA_vwCallReq_AllData 
where ActiveFlag = 1
AND 
(CASE @ImpUrgPri
    WHEN 'PRI' THEN Priority_Enum
    WHEN 'URG' THEN Urgency_Enum
    WHEN 'IMP' THEN Impact_Enum
END) = @Enum
group by 
(CASE @ImpUrgPri
    WHEN 'PRI' THEN Priority_Enum
    WHEN 'URG' THEN Urgency_Enum
    WHEN 'IMP' THEN Impact_Enum
END)
```